# Bounding the Modified Hausdorff Distance

Tags: general-topology, metric-spaces

I'm doing a summer research project on model validation metrics for applications in oil spill modeling.  The idea is to change a single variable in a model one at a time until a certain "metric" is minimized between the model and the observation.  Repeating the process for all relevant variables results in a strong approximation of the observed data.  There's no standard yet since the modelling technique is new, and hopefully significantly improves over the older HYCOM models.  My role is to develop and compare metrics that are sufficiently accurate for our needs.

Currently, I've had good success with the so-called Modified Hausdorff Distance as given by Dubuisson and Jain (http://ieeexplore.ieee.org/xpls/abs_all.jsp?arnumber=576361&tag=1):

\begin{equation*}
d_{MH}(A,B) = \max\left\{\frac{1}{|A|}\sum_{a\in A}d(a,B), \frac{1}{|B|}\sum_{b\in B}d(b,A)\right\},
\end{equation*}
where $A,B\subset\mathbb{R}^n$ such that $|A|,|B|<\infty$.  Also, $d(a,B)=\min_{b\in B}\|a-b\|$, and similarly for $d(b,A)$.

The metric has performed very well in various tests, showing the desired monotonicity with respect to various standard homotopies (translation, scaling, noise).  Additionally, it scored quite well on a facial recognition test I ran using grayscale images from the AT$\&$T Database of Faces (http://www.cl.cam.ac.uk/research/dtg/attarchive/facedatabase.html).

The problem, as stated by the authors, is that the function isn't a topological metric on the space of all finite subsets of $\mathbb{R}^n$ since it fails the triangle inequality.  For the pursposes of our applications, this doesn't seem to be a huge problem since it's done so well in practice.  However, I'd like to at least develop some bounds on this bad behavior.  Namely, I'm stuck on two things:

(1)   I need a good counterexample to the triangle inequality.  Any ideas?  I've had trouble coming up with one, and the authors don't cite any.

(2)   My intuition tells me the counterexample(s) will involve sets with small numbers of points, and if this is the case I'd like to see if I can develop an approximation of the form $d(A,C)\leq d(A,B)+d(B,C)+\epsilon(n)$, where $n=\max(|A|,|B|)$ and $\epsilon:\mathbb{Z}^+\to\mathbb{R}$ monotonically decreases.  Thus for large sample sizes, $d_{MH}$ is essentially a true topological metric.

Any suggestions on how to proceed?  I'm a bit stuck.. any suggestions would be very helpful.

Jon

**EDIT 1**: After further testing, it turns out the suggested value of $K=3/2$ is too small.  I've yet to achieve values of $K>3/2$ in MATLAB simulations in $\mathbb{R}^n$ for $n\in\{2,3,4\}$, however values around $K=3$ are required for $n\not\in \{2,3\}$.

[image: plot]

The above plot shows one such simulation.  For each $k=1,...,10$, I plotted random sets of points $A,B,C\subset\mathbb{R}^k$ and computed $d_{MH}(A,B),d_{MH}(B,C)$, and $d_{MH}(A,C)$ $10^5$ times.  I then found the maximum value of $K$ to force the proposed inquality to hold.  The $x$-axis indicates the dimension, and the $y$-axis indicates the $K$ values.  I'm not quite sure what to make of this yet.  I think it's clear that if such a bounding of the Modified Hausdorff Distance exists, it must be a multiplicative one.  Based on significant empirical evidence, I find it doubtful the function is unbounded.  The behavior on $\mathbb{R}^k$ for $k=1,2,3$ makes sense, but why the increasing behavior for higher dimensions??

**EDIT 2**: As requested, here's an example in $\mathbb{R}$ that forces $K>2$:
\begin{align*}
A &= \{4,11\}\\
B &= \{2,13,14,18,20,26,61\}\\
C &= \{5,53,58,65,79,81\}.
\end{align*}
Then $d_{MH}(A,B)=12.5714,d_{MH}(B,C)=10.2857,$ and $d_{MH}(A,C)=47$.  Thus the smallest $K\in\mathbb{R}$ such that $d_{MH}(A,C)\leq K(d_{MH}(A,B)+d_{MH}(B,C))$ is $K=2.0563$.

The plot isn't terribly illuminating, but I'll include it as requested:
[image: KinR]

**Edit 3:** The following bounds have been disproved:

\begin{align*}
1.& d_{MH}(A,C)\leq d_{MH}(A,B)+d_{MH}(B,C)+\epsilon;\\
2.& d_{MH}(A,C)\leq K(d_{MH}(A,B)+d_{MH}(B,C));\\
3.& d_{MH}(A,C)\leq K\cdot\max\{d_{MH}(A,B),d_{MH}(B,C)\}. 
\end{align*}

Counterexamples to 1 and 2 can be found below.  For 3, choose $A,B,C$ as in (6).  Then, letting $\delta$ denote the minimal distance from a point in $N_{n,r}$ to $N$ for $N\in\{1,2\}$, we have:
\begin{equation*}
d(A,C)\leq\frac{n}{n+1}(n\delta+1), ~~~ d(A,B)\geq\frac{n\delta+1}{n+1},~~~ d(B,C)\geq \delta.
\end{equation*}
Hence
\begin{align*}
d(A,C)\leq K\cdot\max\{d(A,B),d(B,C)\} &\Leftrightarrow K\geq\frac{d(A,C)}{\max\{d(A,B),d(B,C)\}}\\
&\Leftrightarrow K\geq \frac{1+r}{1/n+\delta}\rightarrow \infty
\end{align*}
as $r\rightarrow 0$ and $n\rightarrow\infty$.

Comment: If you can get your program to output a human-readable example in $\mathbb R$ which requires $K>2$, please post it here.... Regarding the increasing behavior: since $\mathbb R^k$ contains an isometric copy of $\mathbb R^m$ for $m<k$, it follows that the best constant in $k$ dimension is a nondecreasing function of $k$. So, the dip at $k=2,3,4$ reflects the randomness of your search procedure, not the actual state of things.

Comment: Not sure if I follow.  $\mathbb{R}^k$ of course contains isometric copies of $\mathbb{R}^m$ for $m<k$, namely the collection of all its subspaces when viewed as a vector space, but this isometry preserves Euclidean distance, not $d_{MH}$.  Also, if $d_{MH}$ were a topological metric, it would be with respect to the space $\mathcal{K}=\{K\mid K\subset\mathbb{R}^k,K \text{ is nonempty and compact}\}$, not $\mathbb{R}^k$. I'm not sure I see how it follows that the function should be nondecreasing.  I'll edit to include a plot and a counterexample with $K>2$ in my question.

Comment: * correction: would be a topological metric with respect to the set of all FINITE subsets of $\mathbb{R}^k$.

Comment: An isometric embedding of metric space $f:X\to Y$ induces an isometric embedding of the space of finite subsets with MH metric. Indeed, for any finite subsets A,B in X we have $d_{MH}(A,B)=d_{MH}(f(A), f(B))$. Thanks for the example, I will try to understand what is going on.

Comment: It appears your program does not implement MH distance correctly. I get 53.5 for the distance between A and B in your example.

Comment: The program is correct.  We have: 
\begin{align*}
d_{MH}(A,B)&=\max\left\{\frac{1}{|A|}\sum_{a\in A}d(a,B),\frac{1}{|B|}\sum_{b\in B}d(b,A)\right\}\\
&=\max\left\{\frac{1}{2}(d(4,B)+d(11,B)),\frac{1}{7}(d(2,A)+...+d(61,A))\right\}\\
&=\max\left\{\frac{1}{2}(2+2),\frac{1}{7}(2+2+3+7+9+15+50)\right\}\\
&=\max\{2,12.5714\}\\
&= 12.5714
\end{align*}

Comment: Thanks, I had a brain freeze. I'll keep thinking of what is going on here.

Comment: Also, I agree that $\max(K)$ should be nondecreasing with respect to $K$.  I'll need to evaluate just how "random" the points are.. 

thanks for the help by the way.

Comment: Ugh, found the source of the problem... my program had been generating sets of random point only in $[0,100]^k$, a silly typo.  I've now fixed it to give points in $[-100,100]^k$ and it seems to be giving the desired reults.  will update my question once i investigate further.

Comment: Unfortunately, there is no $K$ that works for all sets: see the update to my answer. Side remark on $[0,100]^k$ vs $[-100,100]^k$: since the distance is translation-invariant, $[-100,100]^k$ is as good as $[0,200]^k$... not a qualitative change. The issue with random search is that when the parameter space is high dimensional (even with $15$ points in  $\mathbb R$ we have 15 dimensions already), the search will likely miss the strongest counterexamples, although it may give an idea for one.

Comment: excellent update to your answer. as for the program design, there's no random search involved. it produces $n$ sets of random $A,B,C$ and computes the modified Hausdorff distances, so it doesn't miss any counterexamples. when the triangle inequality is violated, it computes $K$ and outputs the sets $A,B,C$ at that iteration. I guess the next step for me is to examine whether it holds in 3 space with $(x,y)$ on a regular grid, which is the scenario of the data I'm working with. i can't imagine it wouldn't..

Comment: The counterexample can also be placed on a grid: one can use only rational numbers, and then multiply all of them by common denominator. Thus, snapping points to the square grid has no consequence unless you also limit the size of the grid by some box $[-L,L]^k$. In the latter case, there will be triangle-type inequalities with constants depending on $L$ and $k$. The constants can be either additive or multiplicative, since the scaling argument from my answer no longer applies.

Comment: Thanks very much for all the help. I've tried several approaches for obtaining a good multiplicative bound, and can show that the triangle inequality holds under certain conditions. However, I think a more promising technique is to define $d_{MH}$ as a $K$-quasi-metric as in: http://www.ams.org/journals/ecgd/2006-10-18/S1088-4173-06-00155-X/S1088-4173-06-00155-X.pdf Conditions (1) and (2) on $d_{MH}$ are the same, but the triangle inequality is replaced by: \begin{equation*} d_{MH}(A,C)\leq K \cdot\max\{d_{MH}(A,B),d_{MH}(B,C)\}. \end{equation*} Notice a true metric is a $2$-quasi-metric.

Comment: sigh... this causes problems as well.  will provide counterexample if you'd like, but i don't want to clog up the thread too much.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A simple counterexample is 
$$A=\{1,2\}, B=\{2,3\}, C=\{3,4\} \tag1$$ all considered as subsets of $\mathbb R$. Indeed, $d_{MH}(A,B)=1/2=d_{MH}(B,C)$,  but $d_{MH}(A,C)=3/2$.

There are some issues with the proposed inequality $$d(A,C)\leq d(A,B)+d(B,C)+\epsilon(n) \tag{2}$$

1. Scaling by $\lambda>0$. Replacing $A,B,C$ by $\lambda A=\{\lambda x: x\in A\}$, $\lambda B$ and $\lambda C$ results in all distances multiplied by $\lambda$. But the term $\epsilon(n)$ does not scale, and this is going to break the inequality (2). For example, putting $A=\{\lambda,2\lambda\}$, $B=\{2\lambda,3\lambda\}$, and $C=\{3\lambda,4\lambda\}$ in (2) we get 
   $$\frac32\lambda \leq \lambda+\epsilon(2) \tag{3}$$ 
   which can't be true with $\epsilon(2)$ independent of $\lambda$.
2. Duplication of points. From a counterexample with small sets such as (1) I can construct counterexamples with almost the same MH-distances and arbitrarily large sets. One way to do this is to replace each set in (1) with the union of its translates by tiny amounts, such as
   $$\bigcup_{k=0}^{1000}(A+k\cdot 10^{-6})=\{1,1+10^{-6},\dots, 1+10^{-3}, 2,2+10^{-6},\dots, 2+10^{-3}\} \tag4$$ 
   Now each set  has $2000$ elements, and none of the MH-distances changed by more than $10^{-3}$.

What *might* be true is an inequality with universal **multiplicative** constant $K>1$, that is,
 $$d(A,C)\leq K(d(A,B)+d(B,C)) \tag{5}$$ 
Example (1) shows that $K$ must be at least $3/2$. So far I have not found any examples that require  $K>3/2$.

**Added**: Unfortunately, (5) does not hold either, for any universal constant $K$. To describe a counterexample, I use notation $a_{n,r}$ which means  $n$ distinct points placed in the $r$-neighborhood of point $a$. For example, the set in (4) could be written as $\{1_{1000,1/1000}, 2_{1000,1/1000}\}$. Consider the sets
$$A=\{1\},\ B=\{1_{n,r},2\}, \ C=\{1, 2_{n,r}\} \tag6$$
Here 
$$\begin{split}d_{MH}(A,B)&\le \frac{1}{n+1}(nr+1) \le r+\frac{1}{n}\\
 d_{MH}(B,C) &\le \frac{1}{n+1}(n+1)r = r\\
 d_{MH}(A,C) &\ge \frac1{n+1}n(1-r) \end{split} \tag7$$
As $n\to\infty$ and $r\to 0$, the first two distances tend to $0$ while $d(A,C)\to 1$.

Comment: Thanks very much!  Very insightful, I think you're spot on with the mutliplicative bound.  I've run some quick tests in MATLAB (in $\mathbb{R}^2$) with up to $10^6$ iterations, and have yet to see $K>3/2$.  I think the counterexample you gave may be the exact worst-case scenario: (embedding in the plane) the points are collinear, have minimal cardinality without reducing to a trivial case, and have maximal intersection without reducing to a trivial case.  I'll run a few more tests in $\mathbb{R}$ and $\mathbb{R}^3$ for kicks, but I think I should be able to prove it without too much trouble.

Comment: Nice answer +1.